# Ran Disk Utility to Repair Permissions but not sure it's doing the right job

Tags: macos, disk-utility, permission

I wrote a script to parse Disk Utility log and output and permission changes that give more access than before.

There were 5 results:

`2014-09-21 21:42:31 +1000: Permissions differ on “usr/lib/libruby.2.0.dylib”; should be lrwxrwxrwx ; they are lrwxr-xr-x .
2014-09-21 21:42:31 +1000: Permissions differ on “usr/lib/libruby.dylib”; should be lrwxrwxrwx ; they are lrwxr-xr-x .
2014-09-21 21:42:32 +1000: Permissions differ on “Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Resources/Safari.help/Contents/Resources/index.html”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rw-r--r-- .
2014-09-21 21:42:34 +1000: Permissions differ on “Library/Printers/InstalledPrinters.plist”; should be -rw-rw-rw- ; they are -rw-r--r-- .
2014-09-21 21:43:09 +1000: Permissions differ on “System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/libruby.2.0.dylib”; should be lrwxrwxrwx ; they are lrwxr-xr-x .`

- What is going on here: `2014-09-21 21:42:32 +1000: Permissions differ on “Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Resources/Safari.help/Contents/Resources/index.html”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ; they are -rw-r--r--`
  ?

Comment: There used to be Apple Support articles that listed which repair permissions errors were "expected" as sometimes later updates changed things but not the BOM and receipts files used to show the permissions. I can't find an "official" list to know if these are "expected" or problematic.

Comment: @bmike The list of Repair permissions that can be ignored is currently at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203172. Many of the items listed by the OP are not on this list.